# Cannot return value from another method

Tags: java, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testing{

public static int getError(int inputnum, int[][] grid, int errorCode){      

    if(inputnum <0 || inputnum > grid[0].length){

        System.out.println("Range of column should be 0 to 6!");
        //change errorCode to 1 to go back to the begining of while loop
        errorCode = 1;
    }

    if(grid[5][inputnum] != 0){

        System.out.println("Column " + inputnum + " is full");
        errorCode = 1;
    }

    return errorCode;
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int player = 1;
    int errorCode = 0;
    int[][] grid = CreateGrid();
    boolean loop = true;

    drawGrid(grid);     
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    while(loop){


    System.out.print("Player " + player + " type a column <0-6> or 9 to quit 
    current game:");

    int inputnum = input.nextInt();         
    getError(inputnum, grid, errorCode);
    errorCode = getError(errorCode);
    if (errorCode == 1)
        continue;
    }
}
```

Not sure why I cannot pass the errorcode from `getError` method to the `main` method. It says:

> **fourinaline_reference_edited.java:140: error: cannot find symbol        errorCode = getError(errorCode2);
>                              ^   symbol:   variable errorCode2   location: class fourinaline_reference_edited 1 error**

How can I solve it?

Comment: The error message and the code you posted are unrelated. Read the message. It's about the file fourinaline_reference_edited.java. And it complains about a variable errorCode2, which doesn't exist in the code you posted.

Comment: This code should throw a different error. There's no method called `getError` that receives only an integer.

Comment: Do you have an overloaded "getError" method ? or you may want to try this  `errorCode = getError(inputnum, grid, errorCode);` instead of this `errorCode = getError(errorCode);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The reason I do not put
    errorCode = getError(inputnum, grid, errorCode);
is that I only need the return value of errorCode in getError method

Answer (score 4):

You don't pass the right type to your method :

```
errorCode = getError(errorCode);
```

your method should take `int, array of int[][], and int`, not just `int`:

```
getError(int inputnum, int[][] grid, int errorCode)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I do not put
           int, array of int[][], and int
is that I only need the return value of errorCode in getError method. Is it possible to retrieve only one variable from a method to which multiple variables have been passed?

Comment: yes this is logic, your method should return only one value or void `0..1`, and can pass `0..*` attribute @LuisSuarez

Comment: But it doesn't work, the following error message still appears.

fourinaline_reference_edited.java:140: error: method getError in class fourinaline_reference_edited cannot be applied to given types;
  errorCode = getError(errorCode);
              ^
  required: int,int[][],int
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: you don't get it @LuisSuarez can you share what you tried to do?

Comment: your call should look like this `errorCode = getError(inputnum, grid, errorCode);` because the signature is of your method is `getError(int inputnum, int[][] grid, int errorCode)`

Comment: just this @LuisSuarez ?

Comment: not just this. Sorry, I am not able to post a full comment due to connection error

What I am trying to do is pass `int errorCode = 0` to getError method from main method. If the user input is larger than 6, the errorCode will change to 1. In the main method, if errorCode is 1, the continue statement will be executed.

Comment: @LuisSuarez did you mean this `if(inputnum>6){
    errorCode = 1;
}else{
    continue;
}` ?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to do it in the getError method instead of main

Comment: mmmm, this is weird, then you can move your while block `errorCode = getError(player, grid, errorCode);` to your method and call your method `getError(player, grid, errorCode);` in the main method @LuisSuarez

Comment: The problem is that I would like to execute a continue statement to restart a while loop in the main method depending the value of errorCode

Comment: @LuisSuarez in this case you have to change the signature of your method, because you can't pass one parameter to a method which accept 3 parameters this is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do

```
errorCode = getError(inputnum,grid,errorCode);
```

directly?